# Java - a file is saved to the wrong directory in S3 when copied from HDFS

Tags: java, file, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

I wrote a method for saving files from an HDFS directory to S3. But the files are getting saved to the wrong directory in S3. I've inspected the logs an have confirmed that the value of `s3TargetPath` is `s3://bucketName/data` and `hdfsSource` is also resolved correctly.

However instead of being saved to the `s3TargetPath` they are saved to `s3://bucketName//data/`.

And also the `s3://bucketName//data/` directory contains a file `data` with a content type: `binary/octet-stream`, fs-type: `Hadoop block`.
What needs to be changed in my code to save files to the right S3 path?

```
private String hdfsPath = "hdfs://localhost:9010/user/usr1/data";
private String s3Path = "s3://bucketName/data";

copyFromHdfstoS3(hdfsPath, s3Path);
```

//

```
void copyFromHdfstoS3(String hdfsDir, String s3sDir) {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(hdfsDir), conf);
FileSystem s3Fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(s3sDir), conf);

Path hdfsSource = new Path(hdfsDir);
Path s3TargetPath = new Path(s3sDir);

RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> sourceFiles = hdfs.listFiles(sourcePath, false);

        if (!s3Fs.exists(s3TargetPath)) {
            s3Fs.mkdirs(s3TargetPath);
        }

        if (sourceFiles != null) {
            while (sourceFiles.hasNext()) {
                Path srcFilePath = sourceFiles.next().getPath();
                if (FileUtil.copy(hdfs, srcFilePath, s3Fs, s3TargetPath, false, true, new Configuration())) {
                    LOG.info("Copied Successfully");
                } else {
                    LOG.info("Copy Failed");
                }
            }
        }    
}
```